# The new android studio?

Tags: java, 2d, android, game-design, textures

I got the new android studio, and I noticed one thing when creating a new activity.

[image]

**The layout that corresponds with the java for the activity is made twice, once as a `content`:**

[image]

This new layout is an exact replica of the regular `activity_menu.xml` except this one is called `content_menu.xml`. I also noticed this piece of code in the layout code of `activity_menu.xml`:

```
    <include layout="@layout/content_menu" />
```

What is the point of this extra layout? Can I delete it? I found [this](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) on the official documentation, but I still don't understand why it is necessary. This wasn't there in the first update...

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: ...This is about game development...I was trying to develop my game, when this weird layout stuff started happening.

Comment: this question itself is not about game development

Comment: If, for example, your computer wouldn't power on when you were trying to develop your game, you wouldn't ask it here.